# SVN commit fails with "Authorization failed" error

Tags: svn

I am a new user with SVN,  and  I meet a problem on SVN commit command.

I use TortoiseSVN 1.6.6, and Ubuntu Subversion image with WMware as server.

I did create a repository on SVN server, and I can easily checkout files from the repository, but commit.

When I do commit, it always shows the problem.

```
Command: Commit  
Error: Commit failed (details follow):  
Error: Authorization failed  
Finished!:
```

This problem only shows at local client with SVN server repository on VM. I tried creating repository on local machine with TortoiseSVN, and it is no problem on Commit. I also tried a working copy on server machine, it is no problem on Commit also.

Did anybody experience this issue? It is not any problem on Checkout from VM SVN server but it shows trouble on local client commit to VM server.

Should anything need to be setup I missed to do it?

Comment: This question's old but I'll add my 2 cents because I recently had this problem.  My issue was the way I checked the repository out.  I inadvertently used svn://example.com/Repo instead of svn+ssh://svn@example.com/Repo as the source, and the anonymous checkout worked fine, but I was unable to commit.  If I'd made sure I'd checked it out the same way as I was doing on other systems I wouldn't have had a problem but I didn't.  Might be worth checking if this is your problem: compare the repo source between working and nonworking and see if there is anything obviously amiss.

Answer (score 20):

For me it was because of server migration.
In svnserve.conf I forgot to uncomment:

```
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
```

Comment: this is my most common error when using new repositories.

Comment: These files are found inside to each repository. Revisit also the files authz and passwd if there are specific users that should be migrated

Answer (score 17):

It's the authorization that failed. That means the first step, the authentication was successful.

So: the username/password is correct and was accepted by your server. But then that user wasn't allowed to access the path/resource.

check your path based authorization file (conf/authz) and make sure that user has the rights.

Answer (score 6):

If the server is using `svnserve` to serve the repository (which means you are using a `svn://` URL) then you should check the file `conf/svnserve.conf` in the repository. The default configuration allows anonymous read, but only authenticated write accesses IIRC.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same issue with `RapidSVN` (or when using `svn commit` from the CLI). The issue turned out that I was checking out the repo using the Anonymous Subversion Access (the `svn://` link):

`svn checkout svn://svn.r-forge.r-project.org/svnroot/rsitesearch/`

But when using this link for the repo you cannot commit changes. So the solution was to use the `svn+ssh://` link allowing Developer Subversion Access via SSH:

`svn checkout svn+ssh://developername@svn.r-forge.r-project.org/svnroot/rsitesearch/`

With other SVN services, the correct link for commit could be `https://`. Actually I have better experience with the `https://` checkout, so try that first.

Now `svn commit` should work as expected.

(This is the same solution as the one suggested by Wug in the comment to the OP.)

Comment: And if you are just messing about on your own local setup, and want to configure something that works but opens up write access potentially dangerously, you can perhaps change a line in svnserve.conf from  
`# anon-access = read` to `anon-access = write` (note **anon**-access, not **auth**-access)

Answer (score 4):

My experience was similar to bluebrother
I'd created a new repository correctly but hadn't setup the users properly. It let me Checkout but not Commit

Edit *repoLocation*/conf/svnserve.conf and uncomment the line

> password-db = passwd

Edit *repoLocation*/conf/passwd and add a username and password to passwd for example

> tim = password

Comment: Just a note: the name and password pair should be set on 'repoLocation/conf/passwd' , not inside 'svnserve.conf' , since with the above line you are telling the service to look up for that file.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, can you browse the repository from Tortoise? If you can, then the user account you are accessing the repository with doesn't have write (=commit) rights.

If you can neither browse not commit: It could be that Tortoise has stored the wrong authentication data on your client. I think it *should* ask for the credentials again in that case, but maybe it doesn't. Try this:

1. Open your Start menu, go to the TortoiseSVN group
2. Click "TortoiseSVN settings"
3. Go to "Saved data"
4. Click "Clear" in "Authentication data"

Tortoise will then forget all stored passwords, and should ask you again next time you try to access the VM.

Comment: I have a similar issue. I don't have any issues for SVN browse, checkout from the SVN Repository. 

This happens only on my laptop. However, If I remote desktop onto other machines, I can check out the code, browse, and also Commit. So whenever I have to check in any code, I will have to copy the code onto Remote machine and check it in. 

I am using Windows 8  - 64bit OS. SVN Version info :
TortoiseSVN 1.8.2, Build 24708 - 64 Bit , 2013/08/27 19:20:39
Subversion 1.8.3, -release
apr 1.4.8
apr-util 1.5.2
serf 1.3.1
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
zlib 1.2.8

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19328149/tortoise-svn-commit-failed-details-below-authorization-failed

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `svnserve` to provide SVN access (i.e. your repository url looks like `svn://server/repo`), make sure your server is allowing write access. In some installations, the server is started with read-only access by default:

```
# The -R option enforces read-only access, i.e. write operations to the
# repository (such as commits) will not be allowed.
SVNSERVE_OPTIONS="-d -R -r /srv/svn/repos"
```

Comment: You saved me a couple of hours! Thanks!

Comment: in what file is that ?

Comment: In your `svnserve.conf` file. See [http://serverfault.com/a/110663/211562](http://serverfault.com/a/110663/211562) for some info on where to find the file.

Answer (score 2):

Check out your files using http protocol instead of svn protocol. I had the same issue as I was checking out the files using svn:// protocol. Later I changed the protocol to http:// and everything started working normal.

Answer (score 0):

Also, double check that the actual repository on the server has the correct file permissions to be written to by the server process (either svnserve or Apache).  It's probably okay since you were able to create the repository in other ways, but it's worthwhile to check just in case.

Answer (score 0):

note: I use sasl, and I found out the hard way that it's case sensitive, and expects lowercase usernames; i.e. "username123" won't match "USERNAME123" in your authz file, albeit they are spelled the same, so maybe *check to make sure your usernames are lowercase (in your authz file)*

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too. @Stefan is right.
In `[repo]/conf/svnserve.conf` we can read:

```
If you don't specify an authz-db, no path-based access control is done.
Uncomment the line below to use the default authorization file.
```

just over `authz-db = authz`.
So, just uncomment this, bring to an authorization failure.