# Tortoise SVN : Commit Failed (details follow) Authorization Failed

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using Tortoise SVN Client Version: 1.8.2, Build 24708 - 64 Bit , 2013/08/27 19:20:39 installed on Windows 7 64 bit Enterprise Edition OS.

From day 1, when I try to commit any file it shows below error.

Command: Commit
Error: Commit failed (details follow):
Error: Authorization failed
Completed!:

Does anyone has any fix for this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured the answer myself. I was using Repo Browser URL beginning with svn:// instead of http://

Now, I started using http and SVN prompts me for login credentials. And also, I am able to check in the files that I have checked out using http.

Comment: So how about accepting your answer, so that others can see that it is already answered?